# Issue NPX with tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css, npx

I'm trying to generate tailwindcss to last.css file with npx on Ubuntu.

**Npx version --> 6.14.4**

**Ubuntu ---> 20.04**

However it isn't working.

My code it's the next:

```
npx tailwindcss build src/styles.css -o public/last.css
```

This it's the mistake I'm receiving.

```
Invalid or unexpected token
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
npx tailwindcss -i src/styles.css -o public/last.css
```

this will generate a css file from `src/styles.css` to `public/last.css`

if you want to minify try this:

```
npx tailwindcss -i src/styles.css -o public/last.css --minify
```

and if you want it to purge unused styles you can try [Purgecss](https://purgecss.com)